# How android works when data is passed through activities with intent?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, operating-system

Hi I want to know a basic mechanism in android platform. We know when we want to pass data to another activity, the normal approach is creating an intent and use the method call `putExtras` to create a tag for the data and pass the data through intent. The called activity will retrieve the data by `getExtras` or similar methods. My question is does this work like clipboard, i.e. putting information in a shared place and later retrieve it? If this is the case, then how this things work? What is the clip board like mechanism working behind?

Comment: Android sources are open. Lurk and see. And no, no clipboard is used - that would make not much sense.

Comment: Use prefernces to achieve not exactly what you want but similar like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you see you will find Bundle in onCreate method like onCreate(bundle). you will have bundle in every activity . bundle is like a briefcase what u do on ONE activity u open that briefcase and put some values in it close that and when you go to another class (activity) let suppose TWO. u take that briefcase open it and get that value out and use it. it doesnt work like clipboard you arnt copying or pasting it. I hope that will help.

Comment: So you are telling same briefcase instance is used for all the activities?

Comment: No. you can have items from briefcase for just from - to class . intent(one.this,two.class); you can have items from ONE to TWO class not in THIRD.